# Angular ng-bind doesn't work in my <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my angular app, I'm using `ng-bind` to display some static information on a `modal`. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="orgTelephone" lang-tag="ActivityReport.NewContact_Modal_Telephone" class="sr-only">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orgTelephone" ng-bind="contact.telephone" placeholder="Placeholder / Hint Texts">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="orgEmail" lang-tag="ActivityReport.NewContact_Modal_Email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="orgEmail" ng-bind="contact.email" placeholder="Placeholder / Hint Texts">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="orgSuggestedFollowup" lang-tag="ActivityReport.NewContact_Modal_Followup" class="sr-only">Follow up</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="orgSuggestedFollowup" ng-bind="contact.followup" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing is, `ng-bind` is indeed working correctly in my `textarea`, on the last .row, but it doesn't output anything in my previous `input` elements.

I don't want to use `ng-model` because I do not want two-way data binding in this modal. I need to be able to revert any changes if the user presses Cancel, which I can't if I use `ng-model`.

Is there a way to make one way data-binding work with `inputs`?

Comment: In this case you should have two different variables. One for input, and second one for other stuff.

Comment: You cannot use ng-bind like this. See documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[text]
Use ng-model instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-bind is for the content of an HTML tag, not an attribute. Use double curly markup instead, like this :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="orgTelephone" value="{{contact.telephone}}" placeholder="Placeholder / Hint Texts">
```

Comment: Such a simple fix, I was over-complicating things in my head. This did indeed solve my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way to work around reverting is to not update the live model and make a copy of the object to edit.

When user is ready to save simply extend the original with the copy.

```
$scope.item={foo:'bar'};
// make standalone copy that is not a reference to original
$scope.editItem = angular.copy($scope.item);

$scope.save = function(){
  // update server and then update local data using extend
  angular.extend($scope.item, $scope.editItem);
}
```

Then use `ng-model` pointed at the `edititem` and the original will remain untouched until you save changes

```
<input ng-model="editItem.foo">
```

Comment: This may very well be the "most correct" answer when it comes to good practices. For now, editing works exactly as intended with just the simple fix suggested by @Derek, but I will probably implement the pattern you suggested whenever I come across a similar problem in the future. Thank you.

Comment: but how are you retrieving edited values? If it requires parsing the dom it's not nearly as clean as copying the original and using 2-way binding and not nearly as easy to test

Comment: I generate a (hidden) modal for each item on my contacts list with ng-repeat, making use of $index to generate unique ids for each modal. Clicking edit opens up this modal, which loads up the contact at contacts[$index].

When I click Save, I use, e.g., $('#' + index + '-contact-name').val() to retrieve the values of each contact field. Hitting cancel just dismisses the modal. This has the interesting side effect of keeping what the user typed in edit mode even if the modal is dismissed and re-opened later.

This is likely incredibly inefficient too.

Comment: yes... sounds like it could be greatly simplified and also shouldn't need jQuery at all for this. Keep in mind that ng-repeat creates child scopes so the editItem can be maintained only at child scope level or in indexed array in controller